# How to add a string in a certain position?

Tags: python, string

Is there any function in Python that I can use to insert a value in a certain position of a string?

Something like this:

`"3655879ACB6"` then in position 4 add `"-"` to become `"3655-879ACB6"`

Answer (score 427, accepted):

No. Python Strings are immutable.

```
>>> s='355879ACB6'
>>> s[4:4] = '-'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

It is, however, possible to create a new string that has the inserted character:

```
>>> s[:4] + '-' + s[4:]
'3558-79ACB6'
```

Comment: Adding to this, you could use negative indices to get a position from the right, e.g. `s[:-4]`

Comment: Using the newer format string parlance: '{0}-{1}'.format(s[:4], s[4:])

Comment: Python strings are not immutable, but they don't support item assignment.

Answer (score 86):

This seems very easy:

```
>>> hash = "355879ACB6"
>>> hash = hash[:4] + '-' + hash[4:]
>>> print hash
3558-79ACB6
```

However if you like something like a function do as this:

```
def insert_dash(string, index):
    return string[:index] + '-' + string[index:]

print insert_dash("355879ACB6", 5)
```

Comment: what is the time complexity of this?

Comment: @Embedded_Mugs  I beleive it is O(n) because 
1. substring selection is O(k)+O(n-k) = O(n) where k is the first part of the string (here k=4)  
2. String concatenation is O(k+1) + O(n) = O(n). The string concatenation is O(n) because strings are mutable and it creates a new string for every concatenation.

Answer (score 38):

As strings are immutable another way to do this would be to turn the string into a list, which can then be indexed and modified without any slicing trickery.  However, to get the list back to a string you'd have to use `.join()` using an empty string.

```
>>> hash = '355879ACB6'
>>> hashlist = list(hash)
>>> hashlist.insert(4, '-')
>>> ''.join(hashlist)
'3558-79ACB6'
```

I am not sure how this compares as far as performance, but I do feel it's easier on the eyes than the other solutions. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Simple function to accomplish this:

```
def insert_str(string, str_to_insert, index):
    return string[:index] + str_to_insert + string[index:]
```

Answer (score 9):

Python 3.6+ using f-string:

```
mys = '1362511338314'
f"{mys[:10]}_{mys[10:]}"
```

gives

```
'1362511338_314'
```

Comment: Works with negative indexes as well
`f"{mys[:-2]}_{mys[-2:]}"`
`'13625113383_14'`

Answer (score 7):

I have made a very useful **[method to add a string in a certain position in Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)**:

```
def insertChar(mystring, position, chartoinsert ):
    mystring   =  mystring[:position] + chartoinsert + mystring[position:] 
    return mystring
```

for example:

```
a = "Jorgesys was here!"

def insertChar(mystring, position, chartoinsert ):
    mystring   =  mystring[:position] + chartoinsert + mystring[position:] 
    return mystring   

#Inserting some characters with a defined position:    
print(insertChar(a,0, '-'))    
print(insertChar(a,9, '@'))    
print(insertChar(a,14, '%'))
```

we will have as an output:

```
-Jorgesys was here!
Jorgesys @was here!
Jorgesys was h%ere!
```

Comment: Why do you calculate the length of the string tho?

Comment: Maybe he wanted to check the index was less than length of the string... and then forgot.

Comment: Python conventionally uses underscore case for function names, not camel case.

Answer (score 2):

I think the above answers are fine, but I would explain that there are some unexpected-but-good side effects to them...

```
def insert(string_s, insert_s, pos_i=0):
    return string_s[:pos_i] + insert_s + string_s[pos_i:]
```

If the index pos_i is very small (too negative), the insert string gets prepended. If too long, the insert string gets appended. If pos_i is between -len(string_s) and +len(string_s) - 1, the insert string gets inserted into the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert a given char at multiple locations, always consider creating a list of substrings and then use `.join()` instead of `+` for string concatenation. This is because, since Python `str` are mutable, `+` string concatenation always adds an aditional overhead. More info can be found [here](https://dock2learn.com/tech/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another simple one-liner-solution ;)

`'-'.join([_string[:4], _string[4:]]`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).