# Python add string before every vowel

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a python code that takes a single imputed line of text and adds the string "tak" before every vowel (y only counting as a vowel if it doesn't begin a word) for example "I like sleep" would come out to "takI ltakitake sltaketakep". I am only just beginning learning to code and as such do not know too many complex functions yet. Below is the code I have thus far, which isn't working at all.

```
text = raw_input("enter the text to be translated")
textSplit = text.split()
count = 0
print len(textSplit)
Vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
while count <= len(text):
  for i in textSplit:
    for i in Vowels:
      count += 1
```

However, I have not been able to figure out how I can slice the string, add "tak" and concatenate it.
Thank you.

edit: can it be done without using the `text.replace` module?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5254445/1377864) might be useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)([aeiou])', r'tak\1', "I like sleep") 
'takI ltakiktake sltaketakep'
```

You can also use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) by looping over the string once for each vowel. Don't forget that strings are immutable in Python so you have to create a new string each time:

```
>>> s="I like sleep"
>>> for v in 'aeiouAEIOU':
...    s=s.replace(v, 'tak'+v)
... 
>>> s
'takI ltakiktake sltaketakep'
```

In this case, the string `s` is either the same as before if the vowel is not found or each vowel is replaced by the string `tak` concatenated to the vowel. A new string is created in either case each time through the loop and assigned to `s`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ignore any leading 'y's, you'll have to finesse it just a bit:

```
text = raw_input("enter the text to be translated")

temp1 = temp2 = text[1:] if text[0] in ['y', 'Y'] else text

for vowel in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']:
    temp2 = temp2.replace(vowel, 'tak{}'.format(vowel))
    temp2 = temp2.replace(vowel.upper(), 'tak{}'.format(vowel.upper()))

text = text.replace(temp1, temp2)
print text
```

For an input of 'I like sleep', this gives:

```
takI ltakiktake sltaketakep
```

'yellow':

```
ytakelltakow
```

'turkey':

```
ttakurktaketaky
```

If, for some reason, you really didn't want to use `str.replace`, you could do it like this:

```
text = raw_input("enter the text to be translated")

temp2 = text[1:] if text[0] in ['y', 'Y'] else text
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']

temp2 = ''.join(['tak{}'.format(letter) if letter.lower() in vowels else letter for letter in temp2])

if text[0] in ['y', 'Y']:
    text = text[0] + temp2
else:
    text = temp2

print text
```

Comment: Yes. I've included a solution that avoids `str.replace`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.sub(r'([aeiou])', r'(exampleReplace)\1', text)
```

Example:

```
text = 'Text'
print(re.sub(r'([aeiou])', r'(exampleReplace)\1', text))
>> T(exampleReplace)ext
```

Comment: I was trying the same thing, but the vowels dissapeared in the result for some reason, what exactly does this \1 do in the replacement text?

Comment: It's the capturing group `([aeiou])`, it's the vowel found

Comment: I'm trying this `print(re.sub(r'([aeiou])', r'(exampleReplace)', text)) ` and this replaces the vowels, if i use `r'(exampleReplace)\1'` as a replacement string, the vowels stay there

Answer (score 0):

The following would work:

```
text = 'I like sleep'
vowels = set("aeiou")
modified_text = ''.join(['tak'+letter if letter.lower() in vowels else letter for letter in text])
print(modified_text)
```

**Output**

```
takI ltakiktake sltaketakep
```

(note: I think you are missing a `k` in your sample output)

Answer (score 0):

Use **list()** instead of **split()**. I have also used [enumerate](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5087f2d786a27b02000041a9) to get the index and value simultaneously.
Modified code:

```
text = "I like banana"
textSplit = list(text)
Vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
for index,letter in enumerate(textSplit):
    if letter.lower() in Vowels:
        textSplit[index] = "tak" + letter
print "".join(textSplit)
```

Output:

```
takI ltakiktake btakantakantaka
```