# Add a character to a string in multiple positions in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python beginner here, sorry if this is a dumb question.

So I have a long string, and I need to add a character in very specific areas of the strings. For example, a | after character number 23, 912, and 1200. I read this [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python), but it only works for adding one character.

Also, the solution needs to be expandable, not just do it 3 times. The code I'm making can have lots of different locations with where I want the character to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to the link that you posted [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python); 
If you would like to repeat the operation for different values, you could create a list containing all index positions where you would like your `|` character to be inserted. 
For example,

```
>>> l = [1, 3, 4]
>>> s = "abcdef"
>>> for i in l:
>>>     s = s[:i] + "|" + s[i:] # as suggested in your link
>>> s
'a|b||cdef'
```

This will allow you to repeat the process for the set of values that you provide in the list. You could also define a function to assist in this, which I could explain if this method is insufficient!

Note, however, that this will insert the character relative to the current iteration. That is, in this example, after adding the `|` at position 1, the next insert position, 3, is different from what it was before the first insert. You could avoid this (if you want) by including a counter variable to offset all the index positions by the number of inserts that have been executed (will require initial list to be ordered).

Comment: Thank you, it works! This may be a dumb question, but how does it work? I'm confused about what for i does. Sorry if this is a dumb question, remember I'm a beginner.

Comment: No problem, I'm not much more experience than you! 
I'm assuming you're confused about the `for i in l:` line. What this does is take each element (which we've named `i`) from the list and perform an operation on it. 
For example, if you did `list = ["cat", "rabbit", "dinosaur"]`, and then
`for animal in list:
    print(animal)`
This would print cat, then rabbit, then dinosaur. Hope that makes some sense, this may help you further https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm.

Answer (score 2):

Not so good at python, hope I can help
According to that site you went to, you can make a while loop to solve the problem

The code should look something like this

```
def insert_dash(string, index, addin):
    return string[:index] + addin + string[index:]
alldone = False
string = input("String: ")
index = " "
while index:
    index = input("Index: ")
    addin = input("Add into: ")
    string = insert_dash(string, index, addin)
```

Hope it helps!

PS: I have NOT tried the code, but I think it will work