# Inserting "-" in string after elements of variable lengths

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert the string                 **"12345678aaaa12345678bbbbbbbb"** to **"12345678-aaaa-1234-5678-bbbbbbbb"** in python?

I am not sure on how to do it, since I need to insert "-" after elements of variable lengths say after 8th element then 4th element and so on.

Comment: What are the criteria for inserting the dash? Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function inserts a char at a postion for a string:

```
def insert(char,position,string):
    return string[:position] + char + string[position:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python strings cannot be mutated. What we can do is create another string with the hyphen inserted in between, as per your wish.

Consider the string s = "12345678aaaa12345678bbbbbbbb"
Giving `s[:8] + '-' + s[8:] will give you 12345678-aaaa12345678bbbbbbbb` 
You can give the hyphen as you wish by adjusting the `:` values.

For more methods to add the hyphen, refer to this question thread for answer as to how to insert hypForhen.
[Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python)

Comment: @NickA edited the answer as per the review comments.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
str = '12345678aaaa12345678bbbbbbbb'

indexes = [8, 4, 4, 4]

i = -1

for index in indexes:
    i = i + index + 1
    str = str[:i] + '-' + str[i:]

print str
```

Prints: `12345678-aaaa-1234-5678-bbbbbbbb`

You are free to change `indexes` array to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this process :

```
def insert_(str, idx):
  strlist = list(str)
  strlist.insert(idx, '-')
  return ''.join(strlist)

str = '12345678aaaa12345678bbbbbbbb'
indexes = [8, 4, 4, 4]
resStr = ""
idx = 0
for val in indexes:
  idx += val
  resStr = insert_(str,idx)
  str = resStr
  idx += 1

print(str)
```

output :

```
12345678-aaaa-1234-5678-bbbbbbbb
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly create the string you want but posting it anyway.

It finds all the indexes where digit becomes alpha and vice versa.
Then it inserts "-" at these indexes.

```
a = "12345678aaaa12345678bbbbbbbb"
lst = list(a)

index = []

for ind,i in enumerate(list(a)[:-1]):
    if (i.isdigit() and lst[ind+1].isalpha()) or (i.isalpha() and lst[ind+1].isdigit()):
        index.append(ind)

for i in index[::-1]:
    lst.insert(i+1,"-")

''.join(lst)
```

'12345678-aaaa-12345678-bbbbbbbb'

Answer (score 0):

If your want do this in one time , you can like this.
   str = "12345678aaaa12345678bbbbbbbb"

```
def insert(char,positions,string):
    result = ""
    for post in range(0, len(positions)):
        print(positions[post])
        if post == 0:
            result += string[:positions[post]] + char
        elif post == (len(positions) -1 ):
            result += string[positions[post-1]:positions[post]] + char + string[positions[post]:]
        else:
            result += string[positions[post-1]:positions[post]] + char
        print(result)

    return result

insert("-", [8, 12, 16, 20], str)
```