# How to scrape next page link in Alibaba

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

My code for scraping data from single page of Alibaba is this one:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy




class AlibotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibot'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box.html']
    
    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        Title = response.xpath('//*[@class="title three-line"]/a/@title').extract()
        Price = response.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/b/text()').extract()
        Min_order = response.xpath('//div[@class="min-order"]/b/text()').extract()
        Response_rate = response.xpath('//i[@class="ui2-icon ui2-icon-skip"]/text()').extract()

        for item in zip(Title,Price,Min_order,Response_rate):
            scraped_info = {
                'Title':item[0],
                'Price': item[1],
                'Min_order':item[2],
                'Response_rate':item[3]

            }
            yield scraped_info
```

I want to scrape data from all the pages how do i do that cause it is javascript action while clicking the next page. I have multiple links not just this one. So i want some way that it can go through next page until last page and scrape data from it.

The html snippet is this one:

```
<div class="ui2-pagination-pages">
<span class="prev disable">Prev</span>
 <span class="current">1</span>
  <a rel="nofollow" href="//www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_2.html">2</a>
  <a rel="nofollow" href="//www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_3.html">3</a>
  <a rel="nofollow" href="//www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_4.html">4</a>
 <a rel="nofollow" href="//www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_5.html">5</a>
 
   <a rel="nofollow" href="//www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_6.html">6</a>
 <a rel="nofollow" href="//www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_7.html">7</a>
 
 
                         <span class="interim">...</span>
 
            
                        <a rel="nofollow" href="//www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_103.html">103</a>
 
 
             

                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next" data-role="next">Next</a>
 
                         

             
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All addresses have a pattern `https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_(page).html`, you can modify the `page` field to scrape different pages.

```
# OUTPUT:
# 2018-08-19 11:28:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_2.html> (referer: None)
# 2018-08-19 11:28:33 [alibot] INFO: counter clear custom plexiglass display box for wine red wine champagne display acrylic box -  US $4-50
# 2018-08-19 11:28:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_1.html> (referer: None)
# 2018-08-19 11:28:34 [alibot] INFO: wine glass acrylic whisky beverage led bottle display rack box stands -  US $16.88-26.88

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class AlibotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'alibot'
  allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
  start_urls = [ 
    "https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_" + str(x) + ".html"
    for x in range(1, 3) # pages to scrape
  ]

  def parse(self, response):
    Title = response.xpath('//*[@class="title three-line"]/a/@title').extract()
    Price = response.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/b/text()').extract()
    Min_order = response.xpath('//div[@class="min-order"]/b/text()').extract()
    Response_rate = response.xpath('//i[@class="ui2-icon ui2-icon-skip"]/text()').extract()

    self.logger.info(Title[0] + " - " + Price[0])
```

Comment: thanks, but one problem, i have multiple urls in a csv file not just one so how do i loop through all of that?

Comment: @UchihaAJ Do you mean you need to scrape multiple kinds of products? If is, I think that pattern will work. For example, you can scrape `wine-box` with pattern `https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/wine-box_(page).html`. You can refer to [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python) to construct your URL.

Comment: with open('data.csv') as file:
    start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]                                                                               thanks by the way