# Insert a character to a string with Python

Tags: python-3.x

How do I add a character to a string with Python? For example, I like to add a ":" to the middle of string: "0900" between 09 & 00.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html).

```
time = "0900"
time_with_colon = time[:2] + ":" + time[2:]
print(time_with_colon)
```

> 09:00

You can't mutate a string, but you can slice it to get half of the string before an index and the half after the index. Then combine the two sides with the character you want in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

```
_input = '0900'
input_to_list = list(_input)
input_to_list.insert(round(len(input_to_list)/2), ':')
_input_updated = "".join(input_to_list)
```

Comment: This caught me out too!  There is a bug in your code: `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`. (hint: dividing two numbers leaves a float value).  The method is good though.  Please correct it so that I can up-vote

Comment: @Simon Thanks for pointing out this bug, I've updated the code. Now I think it's good to completely forget python2 :)

Answer (score 1):

To insert characters into a certain position you want to use something called slicing.  You can have a look here to see the exact method: [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python)

Assuming you *always* want to insert into the middle of a string of varying length then this would work as long as the sum of the characters is even (to be clear the sum of the characters you have provided is 4). Then the following would work fine:

```
string = "0099"
pos = int(len(string)/2)
new = string[:pos] + ":" + string[pos:]
print(new)
```

This won't work however if your string isn't of an even amount, when all the characters are added together, the `:` will go in the wrong place.

Sadly just using `int()` on a decimal value will not round it, it converts it to an integer by just copping off any floating value.  As this example demonstrates:

```
>>> int(3.9)
3
```

instead you would want to use the `round()` function:

```
pos = round(len(string)/2)
```