# add list of substrings to specific positions of string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

i have a big string **s** , and a list of coordinates that i must put some strings in there.

```
s = "Hello world this is my code"
```

and a list of positions :

```
cl = [(4,"this") , (7,"that") , (10 , "other")]
```

result :

```
out >> Hell<this>o w<that>orl<other>d this is my code
```

i read this link : [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python) and it is easy to push one string inside other but when i push multi times the positions change . how should i do that?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `enumerate`:

```
s = "Hello world this is my code"
cl = [(4,"this") , (7,"that") , (10 , "other")]
new_cl = dict(cl)
result = ''.join(a if i not in new_cl else f"<{new_cl[i]}>{a}" for i, a in enumerate(s))
```

Output:

```
'Hell<this>o w<that>orl<other>d this is my code'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in reverse order so that the positions of the items in the front aren't affected:

```
for pos, text in reversed(cl):
    s = f'{s[:pos]}<{text}>{s[pos:]}'
```

`s` becomes: `'Hell<this>o w<that>orl<other>d this is my code'`

Comment: If the order is unknown: `sorted(cl, reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
s = "Hello world this is my code"
cl = [(4,"this") , (7,"that") , (10 , "other")]

i = 0
for j,w in cl:
    s = s[:j+i] + w + s[j+i:]
    i += len(w)
```

Just add the length of each added word at each step. Hope this helps!