# How do I insert a string into a specific section of a larger string?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a little program that automatically generates a number of URLs, each basically the same except with the one difference of having a different foreign language abbreviation inserted into each one.

For example, I have this code:

```
base_url = 'https://habitica.fandom.com/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere'
wiki_page = '/File:Gold.png'
languages = ['da', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'ja', 'nl', 'pl', 'pt-br', 'ru', 'tr', 'zh']
```

So I want to insert each of those language abbreviations into the base_url value at the spot before "wiki," leading to

```
https://habitica.fandom.com/da/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/de/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/es/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
```

and so forth.

How should I go about doing this? Is there a fairly general way, or do I need to get into some very detailed code about the specific text of the strings?

Thanks!
John

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a template `str`ing and `format` it like,

```
>>> languages
['da', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'ja', 'nl', 'pl', 'pt-br', 'ru', 'tr', 'zh']
>>> template = 'https://habitica.fandom.com/{}/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere'
>>> urls = []
>>> for lang in languages:
...   urls.append(template.format(lang))
... 
>>> print('\n'.join(urls))
https://habitica.fandom.com/da/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/de/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/es/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/fr/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/it/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/ja/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/nl/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/pl/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/pt-br/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/ru/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/tr/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
https://habitica.fandom.com/zh/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere
>>>
```

Comment: FYI the concept applied here is called [string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: Ah yes, I had just read about the various ways of doing string formatting not that long ago, and I didn't even realize this is what I needed! In fact, would it be even better to use f-strings?

Comment: In this case, it is best to use `str.format` instead of `f-strings`