# How to append strings to a specific position in an array with for loop

Tags: python, linux

I am new to python and Linux. I found a problem while trying append strings to a specific position in an array with a for loop.
 This is simplied description of my work.

This is my input file1:
a,b,c,d,e,f

Input file2:
name1,a,b,d,e
name2,b,e,f

I would like to get the output file that the same letter will be in the same column as shown below:

```
  a,b,c,d,e,f
  name1,a,b,0,d,e,0
  name2,0,b,0,0,e,f
```

I search for Linux scripts but so far I could not found the suitable one. Then, I tried with NumPy array in python but there is only np.insert or np.append function but they seem to not appropriate for my situation.
Following is the python script that I processed

```
    import numpy as np
    header = np.loadtxt("file1.txt", dtype= str, delimiter=',')
    lines = np.loadtxt("file2.txt", dtype= str, delimiter=',')
    ARG = np.empty([2,7], dtype=str)
    for x, line in enumerate(lines):
       for i in line:
          for y, j in enumerate(header):
             if i == j:
               np.insert(ARG, y, i, axis=x)
               print(ARG)
             else:
               np.insert(ARG, y, 0, axis=x)
    np.savetxt('test.csv', ARG, delimiter=',')
```

The output shows an error like IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2, and the added strings were not at the correct position in the array.
Would you mind giving me some suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python

Comment: Hi Pham, welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have just edited my post. Hope this will make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `insert` function does the work here:

```
my_list1 = ['name1','a','b','d','e']
my_list2 = ['name2','b','e','f']

my_list1.insert(3,0)
my_list1.insert(7,0)

my_list2.insert(1,0)
my_list2.insert(4,0)
my_list2.insert(5,0)
print(my_list1)
print(my_list2)
```

output:

```
['name1', 'a', 'b', 0, 'd', 'e', 0]
['name2', 0, 'b', 'e', 0, 0, 'f']
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is the simplified description of my work. Actually, file 2 contains 210 lines, so I am looking for using a for loop. Do you have any suggestions?