# How to insert random characters into a string

Tags: python, encryption

I am writing a program to scramble strings. The program should reverse the input string, and insert a random symbol every 6th character.

Here is what I have:

```
word =  input("Type the string to ecrypted  ")
symbols = list("!@#$%^&*()1234567890_-+=")
word = word[::-1]

for letter in word:
    if letter % 2 == 0 and letter % 3 == 0:
        # what do I put here??????????????
print(word)
```

I am stuck on how to insert random characters into the string.

Comment: `letter % 2` doesn't make sense. `letter` is a character, not a number.

Comment: What do you want to do there?

Comment: As a point of semantics, using the term "encryption" generally gets people's hackles up because in general you should leave security sensitive things to the experts (most professional programmers even are not security experts)

Comment: `letter % 2 == 0 and letter % 3 == 0` can be simplified to `letter % 6 == 0`

Comment: And inserting random characters isn't any form of encryption. At best it's obfuscation.

Comment: @Aaron & Barmar, it is actually by its very definition exactly that - encryption. It might not be a very adequate one, compared to modern security standards, but it's still encryption and can be called that. Same goes for the famous Caesar Cipher and other such basic examples.

Comment: Ok i want to make it harder to figure out is there a way I can insert characters in The Middle

Comment: Strings in Python are immutable, you can't insert into them. You should concatenate each character to a new string, and concatenate your random characters in the `if`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can roughly see what you're going for, but correct me if I'm wrong:

You want to scramble a message by reversing the input string, and add a random symbol every 6th character.

You have already reversed the string, and are iterating over each character, but are not figuring out how to build the new string with randomized symbols.

If you want to count every 6th character, you'll need a number to track each character in addition to the character itself. For this it is very convenient to use the `enumerate` function in your `for` loop. Then you can use math to figure out if you're on the 6th character or not:

```
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    if index % 2 == 0 and index % 3 == 0:
        # what do I put here??????????????
print(word)
```

From there you need to start building your new output string (you can only ever make a new string in python, never modify an existing one. Overwriting the variable may look like modifying an existing string, but internally it creates an entire new one before overwriting the existing one which is why you can't do something like this: `my_string[3] = 'G'`). For this we'll create a variable which we'll add the characters to in order:

```
new_word = '' #empty string
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    new_word = new_word + letter
    if index % 2 == 0 and index % 3 == 0:
        # what do I put here??????????????
print(new_word)
```

Now to get a random symbol to add every 6th character, we'll use the `random` library by calling `import random` at the beginning of the script. The `random.choice()` function will choose a random element from your list of symbols which we can then add to the `new_word` we're building.

```
new_word = '' #empty string
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    new_word = new_word + letter
    if index % 2 == 0 and index % 3 == 0:
        random_char = random.choice(symbols)
        new_word = new_word + random_char
print(new_word)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is very informative and userful

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Python are immutable, so you need to create new strings to combine the characters from `word` and random symbols.

When testing whether to insert a random character you need to use the index, not the character. You can get both the index and character with `enumerate()`.

If you want to insert the random characters after every multiple of 2 and also after every multiple of 3, you need to use `or`, not `and`.

```
import random

word =  input("Type the string to ecrypted  ")
symbols = list("!@#$%^&*()1234567890_-+=")
word = word[::-1]

encrypted = ""
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    encrypted += letter
    if index % 2 == 0 or index % 3 == 0:
        encrypted += random.choice(symbols)
print(encrypted)
```