# place a decimal point function in python

Tags: python, function, decimal

I am looking to write a function in python that places a decimal point into some string.

for example if the string I give is `'12355'` and then I put the point place in `2`
the output should skip the first two numbers and show `'12.355'`

please help,
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
place = 3
number = "12345"
result = number[:place] + "." + number[place:]
print(result)
```

The result will have the decimal point 3 characters from the first one.
When I run it the output is

```
123.45
```

If you were to do a function, then

```
def insert_decimal(position,number):
  return number[:position] + "." + number[position:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string indexing, as if it were a list:

```py
def insert_decimal_point(number, position):
    return number[:position] + "." + number[position:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def add_decimal_point(s, n):
    return f'{s[:n]}.{s[n:]}' if 0 < n < len(s) else s

add_decimal_point("23567", 2)

23.567
```

If `n` is greater or equal to the length of the string or if it is negative, the original string is returned:

```py
add_decimal_point("23567", 10)

23567
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can treat this string mathematically as a number:

```
s = "12355"
n = float(s)
length = len(s)

place = 2
power = length - place

print(n / (10 ** power))
```

lets separate logic into the function:

```
def decimal_point(s, place):
        n = float(s)
        length = len(s)
    
    
        power = length - place
    
        return n / (10 ** power)
```