# Add string in a certain position in column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Basically this:

```
hash = "355879ACB6"
hash = hash[:4] + '-' + hash[4:]
print (hash)
3558-79ACB6
```

[I got this part above from another stackoverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python)

but for a DataFrame.

I am only able to successfully add strings before and after, like this:

```
data ['col1'] = data['col1'] + 'teststring'
```

If I try the solution from the link above `[:amountofcharacterstocutafter]` to add values at a certain position, which would be something like:

```
test = data[:2] + 'zz'
print (test)
```

It does not seem to be applicable, as the `[:2]` operator works different for dataframes as it does for strings. It cuts the ouput after the first 2 rows.

Goal:
I want to add a ' - ' at a certain position. Let's say the input row value is 'TTTT1234', output should be 'TTTT-1234'. For every row.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. I like your questions: they are clear. You have accepted that answer below as an appropriate answer to your question, that is very good. You can also up vote one or more answers if they are useful. They deserve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform the operation you presented on a list but you have a column in  a dataframe so its (a bit) different.

So while you can do this:

```
hash = "355879ACB6"
hash = hash[:4] + '-' + hash[4:]
```

in order to do this on a dataframe you can do it in at least 2 ways:

consider this dummy df:

```
    LOCATION    Hash
0   USA         355879ACB6
1   USA         455879ACB6
2   USA         388879ACB6
3   USA         800879ACB6
4   JAPAN       355870BCB6
5   JAPAN       355079ACB6
```

A. **vectorization**: the most efficient way

```
df['new_hash']=df['Hash'].str[:4]+'-'+df['Hash'].str[4:]

    LOCATION    Hash        new_hash
0   USA         355879ACB6  3558-79ACB6
1   USA         455879ACB6  4558-79ACB6
2   USA         388879ACB6  3888-79ACB6
3   USA         800879ACB6  8008-79ACB6
4   JAPAN       355870BCB6  3558-70BCB6
5   JAPAN       355079ACB6  3550-79ACB6
```

B. **apply lambda:** intuitive to implement but less attractive in terms of performance

```
df['new_hash'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Hash'][:4]+'-'+x['Hash'][4:], axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you. I used A, followed by dropping the old column.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pd.Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html). For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "c": ["TTTT1234"]
})
df["c"].str[:4] + "-" + df["c"].str[4:] # It will output 'TTTT-1234'
```

pd.Series.str gives vectorized string functions.