# Pandas dataframe how to add "-" at position before last letter in a column

Tags: python, pandas, split

My dataset is as the example below:

```
Index ID
0     1.4A
1     1.4D
2     5B
3     D6C
4     ZG67A   
5     ZG67C
```

I want to add a "-" before the last position of the values in my column. The values don't have a consitent lenght, therefore I cannot choose a position to place the - between, [as in this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493713/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-column-in-dataframe)

One good solution in the related post is to use pd-Series.str and to chose a position

`df['ID'.str[2:] + "-" + df["c"].str[4:]`

I somehow need to address the position before the last letter in every row in my column['ID']. Later I want to apply split, but as far as I understood split, it needs a delimiter to split.

Best Outcome:

```
Index ID
0     1.4-A
1     1.4-D
2     5-B
3     D6-C
4     ZG67-A   
5     ZG67-C
```

Thanks

Comment: use this for the last letter ```df['ID'] = df['ID'].str[:-1] + "-" + df["'ID'"].str[-1]```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["ID"] = df["ID"].str.replace(r"(.*)([A-Z]+)$", r"\1-\2", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Index      ID
0      0   1.4-A
1      1   1.4-D
2      2     5-B
3      3    D6-C
4      4  ZG67-A
5      5  ZG67-C
```

Comment: Nice but you [don't need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73790621/16343464) the capturing groups :p

Answer (score 1):

you can reference positions relative to the end of a string using negative indices, just like normal list or string indexing:

```py
df['ID'].str[:-1] + "-" + df["ID"].str[-1:]
```

If you're hoping to split out the last character in each string, you could use a regular expression to match exactly one character before the end - no delimiter needed:

```py
In [9]: df.ID.str.split(r'(?=.$)', regex=True)
Out[9]:
Index
0     [1.4, A]
1     [1.4, D]
2       [5, B]
3      [D6, C]
4    [ZG67, A]
5    [ZG67, C]
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of your answers work perfectly. Later I split The letters and use them in a new column to group my dataset.

Comment: if you want to split this out into two new columns, you can pass `expand=True` to [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex to match the position before the last character (using a lookahead):

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace(r'(?=.$)', '-', regex=True)
```

output (as new column ID2 for comparison):

```
   Index     ID     ID2
0      0   1.4A   1.4-A
1      1   1.4D   1.4-D
2      2     5B     5-B
3      3    D6C    D6-C
4      4  ZG67A  ZG67-A
5      5  ZG67C  ZG67-C
```