# How to add a colon in a string, Python?

Tags: python, string

I've got an array of elements of 4 numbers that are classed as strings, and I want to add a colon in between 2 of the numbers of every element so it looks like a time, but how do you do this:

```
STarray = ['0712', '0819', '1131', '1352', '1401']
```

Comment: `[f'{i[:2]}:{i[2:]}' for i in STarray]`? Strings are immutable, so you can't actually insert characters in them. You need to build new strings.

Comment: Can you *show* what you want produced from this example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a string in a certain position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/how-to-add-a-string-in-a-certain-position)

Comment: I was hoping it would eventually look like STarray = ['07:12', '08:19', '11:31', '13:52', '14:01'], so how would I use that code so it would apply to all of the elements because I'm not the best at coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for this.

Something like

```py
STarray = [f"{el[:2]}:{el[2:]}" for el in STarray]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tou could use old style formatting in a list comprehension:

```
['%s%s:%s%s'%(*s,) for s in STarray]

# ['07:12', '08:19', '11:31', '13:52', '14:01']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `.format()`:

```py
new = ["{}{}:{}{}".format(*item) for item in STarray]
```