# Adding comma after a character in string

Tags: python

```
number = input("Enter the number:")
''' Let's suppose the entered number is 0145. Question is below.'''
```

I want to add a comma after 0.
How can i do this?

Comment: What is your current output? What is the exact output you want?

Comment: Are you looking for commas with long integers (e.g. 1,000) or somethng like "0,145" ??

Comment: The output i want is 0,145

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. `0145` isn't a valid `int`; it gets converted to just `145`. So the situation you're describing is not possible, unless you want something like `'0,' + str(number)`, but that seems silly. Please [edit] and clarify what you're trying to accomplish. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: Did you mean you want to add a character at a certain position in a string like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/how-to-add-a-string-in-a-certain-position)? The `input()` function returns a string already. If you do `int(input(...` you will lose any leading `0` chars.

Comment: Yes i know, i am trying to make it a decimal number in a string. Just i want is adding a comma after the first character of a string basically.

Comment: Thanks, quamrana. That is what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use `{:,}` to format a number with commas in Python.

Example:

```python
number = 1000
print(f"{number:,}")
```

**Output:**
 
1,000

If want a general purpose number formatter for numbers as strings that may include leading 0's then there is a solution using regular expressions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205875/543969).
If user enters "0145" and want to format that as "0,145" then you'd need to use the string input rather than converting to an integer which would drop any leading 0's.

Comment: Well, this works. But what i want is that the value n should be a string. This doesn't seem work with a string value.